# Insert code in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to show loader effect while image load:

```
$(function(){
   jQuery('figure').append('<div class="loader"><div class="bounce1"></div><div class="bounce2"></div><div class="bounce3"></div></div>');
   jQuery('.img').load(function(){
      jQuery('.loader').remove();
   });
});
```

But I want this code in a function so that I can call it on any image. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xvLe7fw7/)

Comment: And what is your specific question? You can learn about functions in the MDN JavaScript guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: Remove `$(` at start , add `function **name**()` , remove `)` at end of piece at OP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are passing to `$()` is already a function which is anonymous.

If you want to call it somewhere else you can simply give it a name like

```
function showSoader(){
  jQuery('figure').append('<div class="loader"><div class="bounce1"></div><div class="bounce2"></div><div class="bounce3"></div></div>');
  jQuery('.img').load(function(){
     jQuery('.loader').remove();
  });
}
```

You can bind it to ready like `$(showSoader)` and call it anywhere else like `showSoader()`.

If you want to generalize it to work with multiple elements, simply specify a parameter to access the element:

```
function showSoader(selector){
  var $elm = $(selector);
  $elm.append('<div class="loader"><div class="bounce1"></div><div class="bounce2"></div><div class="bounce3"></div></div>');
  $elm.find('.img').load(function(){
     $elm.find('.loader').remove();
  });
}
```

Which you call call like `showSoader("#myImgContainer")`

worth noticing:

> ### Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Answer (score 0):

> **JQuery**

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
   loadImage: function() {       
      return this.each(function() {
         var loading= jQuery('<div class="loader"><div class="bounce1"></div><div class="bounce2"></div><div class="bounce3"></div></div>').insertBefore(jQuery(this));
         jQuery(this).load(function(){   
            loading.remove();
         }).error(function() {
            loading.remove();
         });
      });
   }
});
$(".img").loadImage();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/o5xpkfaz/)